# How to combine two files by inserting lines at multiple different locations with awk/sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have two files: file1.txt and file2.txt. The first one, file1.txt, contains lots of information and in irregular intervals it shows the word TIMESTEP. The second one, file2.txt, on the other hand, contains only a single column of integer values. I would like to parse through file1.txt, find the lines with TIMESTEP and replace the **following** line with the next line from file2.txt. As an example:

file1.txt

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
54
abc
def
ghi
jkl
ITEM: TIMESTEP
55
horse
cat
dog
ITEM: TIMESTEP
56
tree
ITEM: TIMESTEP
57
house
school
...
```

file2.txt

```
150
68
201
202
...
```

Combine them to get:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
150
abc
def
ghi
jkl
ITEM: TIMESTEP
68
horse
cat
dog
ITEM: TIMESTEP
201
tree
ITEM: TIMESTEP
202
house
school
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a short script in `awk`. You can find an `awk` tutorial for example at [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/index.htm). Do it like so,: Pass to `awk` two files. First load the `file2.txt` into an array. Then for each line from `file1.txt`, if a line matches `/TIMESTEP/`, print the line, `getline` next line and print a number from the array. You will need an index in the other array - increment it after printing the number from an array.There are many `awk` tutorials on the net, it's an easy language, you'll learn it in no time!

Comment: No, don't getline the next line as that's error prone, hard to enhance, and unnecessary. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/TIMESTEP/{n;R file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

After encountering a line containing `TIMESTEP` print and then fetch the next line, read/print a line from file2 and then delete the current line from file1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { vals[NR]=$0; next }
    found { $0=vals[++cnt]; found=0 }
    /TIMESTEP/ { found=1 }
    { print }
' file2 file1
ITEM: TIMESTEP
150
abc
def
ghi
jkl
ITEM: TIMESTEP
68
horse
cat
dog
ITEM: TIMESTEP
201
tree
ITEM: TIMESTEP
202
house
school
```

Comment: Thanks, Ed! This works perfectly. Just for completeness sake, in your code file2 is my file1.txt and file1 is my file2.txt -- in case someone looks for this too in the future!

Comment: No, my file1 is your file1.txt etc. You're welcome.